# My httphandler is not invoking

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have problem with my custom HttpHandler. 
1. So in my solution I add a project - class library - Handler(so namespace is Handler)

2. And I add my MyHandler.css class which implements IHttphandler interface in this class library.
3. Next in

   the web config of MySite project I add this

   ```
   <system.web>
            <httpHandlers>
              <add verb="*" path="*.ascx" type="Handler.MyHandler, MySite "/>
            </httpHandlers>
   ```

But when I try to see what happens if I try to access a .ascx file in my site
I get the error

```
HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.
```

Why my httphandler is not invoked
Thank you inadvance

Answer (score 1):

This is because the [IIS Request Filtering module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831621.aspx) is configured to reject requests for .ascx files and the filtering module is responding to the request earlier in the IIS pipeline than your handler. Have a read of [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx) for a detailed outline.

You can configure Request Filtering in IIS "proper" by using the IIS Manager tool, or if you're using IIS Express by editing your `applicationhost.config` file which you'll find located at `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` where you'll be looking for the string:

```
<add fileExtension=".ascx" allowed="false" />
```

If you don't want to change the request filtering configuration, you could always consider re-implementing your Handler as a Module which would mean inheriting from `IHttpModule` instead of `IHttpHandler` and doing more of the leg work yourself.